# Unable to toggle Navigation Drawer (it freezes) after replacing a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

I used Navigation Drawer to setup a Drawer.
In my MainActivity on the onCreate method, I have the following setup

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame.setId(CONTENT_VIEW_ID);
        setContentView(frame, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));      
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            setFragment(0);
        }
    }
```

And my setFragment Method, within the Main Activity is this:

```
public void setFragment(int id) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    switch(id){
    case 0:
        fragmentTransaction.add(CONTENT_VIEW_ID, FragOne.newInstance()).commit();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragmentTransaction.replace(CONTENT_VIEW_ID,FragTwo.newInstance()).commit();
        break;
    }

}
```

note I've declared CONTENT_VIEW_ID as:

```
    private static final int CONTENT_VIEW_ID = 666;
```

When the application starts, it loads the fragment one and it works fine.
When I swipe open the Navigation drawer and select the position 1, it replaces the current fragment with the FragTwo, but right after that the navigation drawer freezes, I can't access it anymore.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue, I been searching online for awhile now and couldn't find a solution to my problem, that why I have decided to ask here, thank you in advanced :)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not inflating a layout, [like Google suggests](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout)?

Comment: As adneal says, you could do this much easier with a layout xml file. And you've not posted any navigation drawer related code; makes debugging a navigation drawer issue a spot difficult.

Comment: @adneal since I will be loading the FragOne first, it inflates the view (it inflates the activity_main view)

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have all the other needed code t make a drawerLayout work fine, I think you should use `.replace(...)` in both cases. It works for me, even though it freezes a little while fragment is being load before it finishes closing.